# Appending table columns values uniquely

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below I have 2 tables with 3 columns each are having values for past and present based on `QuestionId` and forms they are attached to.

1. `presentValueTable` - it has `questionId` and values of present.
2. `pastValueTable`  - it has `questionId` and values from the past for the same `QuestionId`.

Code:

```
-- this code is re-runable 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#presentValueTable') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #presentValueTable
END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#pastValueTable') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #pastValueTable
END

CREATE TABLE #presentValueTable 
(
    Id Int IDENTITY(1, 1),
    QuestionId INT,
    AssignForm INT,
    Value INT
)

CREATE TABLE #pastValueTable
(
    Id Int IDENTITY(1,1),
    QuestionId INT,
    AssignForm INT, 
    Value INT 
)

-- please run this once to insert the date 
/*
INSERT INTO #presentValueTable (QuestionId, AssignForm, Value)
VALUES (12, 35, 100), (12, 35, 200), (12, 35, 300), (12, 35, 400), (12, 35, 500)   --5 rows inserted

INSERT INTO #pastValueTable (QuestionId, AssignForm, Value)
VALUES (12, 45, 99), (12, 45, 199), (12, 45, 299), (12, 45, 399), (12, 45, 499)   --5 rows inserted
*/

SELECT * FROM #presentValueTable
SELECT * FROM #pastValueTable
```

[image: ![Image of the Select query for both the tables]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYFej.jpg)

This is what I expect as output - 3 columns with 10 rows. Each table has 5 rows so when i select i want 10 rows.

```
 QuestionId | AssignForm |  Value | 
 -----------+------------+--------+
 12              35        100 
 12              35        200 
 12              35        300 
 12              35        400 
 12              35        500 
 12              45        99 
 12              45        199 
 12              45        299 
 12              45        399 
 12              45        499
```

Thank you for having a look.

Comment: Does it matter that there is no order to the rows in a table? You seem to want a mix of past and present data in a bag of rows. Lacking a question, it's hard to tell. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: What more imformation you want . I have provided every detail i could with the screen shot  together with what i expect as outcome. WHAT ELSE YOU WANT ?

Comment: As sri has shown, `union` can be used to combine the results of two `select` statements while eliminating duplicate rows. The word "uniquely" in the title of your post _may_ indicate that you want duplicates eliminated, but your question isn't very specific in that regard and it cannot be discerned from the sample data you provided. It also isn't clear whether it is important that the _present_ values appear in the results before the _past_ values. The three columns you want don't provide any way to order the rows that way. (I can read your comment quite well without you resorting to yelling.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select pr.QuestionId,pr.AssingForm,pr.Value
from  #presentValueTable  as pr
union 
select pa.QuestionId,pa.AssingForm,pa.Value
from  #pastValueTable  as pa
order by QuestionId,AssingForm
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please use `code` block for any code. Its improves readability of code.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have done i will be happy to unmark my answer if i find a better answer.
I pass the questionId everytime and query the 2 table and add it in a new Temp Table.
I feel like i need to iterate through it in order to be more dynamic.

```
 CREATE Procedure GetAllPastPresentValueByQuestionId @QuestionId INT
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    CREATE Table #tableAll 
    (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY Identity(1,1),
    QuestionId INT, 
    AssignForm INT ,
    Value INT, 
    )
    INSERT INTO  #tableAll (QuestionId, AssignForm,Value)
    SELECT p.QuestionId,p.AssingForm,p.Value   FROM #pastValueTable as p WHERE QuestionId = @QuestionId
    INSERT INTO #tableAll (QuestionId, AssignForm,Value)
    SELECT p.QuestionId,p.AssingForm,p.Value   FROM #presentValueTable as p WHERE QuestionId = @QuestionId


    SELECT * FROM #tableAll
    END 
    GO
```